# Вложенный запрос в Spring можно сделать только в jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, jdbc, hql

Правильно я понимаю, что запрос подобный этому сделать в Spring можно сделать только в jdbcTemplate или в @Query с nativeQuery=True? В HQL или где то еще нельзя такую вложенность запросов применить?
Т.е. такой вложенный запрос можно сделать только обращаясь непосредственно к таблицам БД, не к сущностям?

```
SELECT
    counts.documentsCount,
    employee.name
FROM
    (SELECT 
        count(d.id) documentsCount,
        d.employee_id 
    FROM
        document d
    where 
        d.created_on between ? and ?
    GROUP BY
        employee_id
    ORDER BY 
        ordersCount DESC                 
    LIMIT 10) counts
LEFT JOIN employee 
    on counts.employee_id = employee.id
```

Answer (score 0):

В hql нельзя делать подзапросы. Нативный  sql можно. Дело в том, что сущности и так маппятся в таблицы, поэтому нет смысла обращаться к таблицам.

Comment: К сущностям обращаться нельзя в SQL.

Comment: На другой вопрос я дал ответ.

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.